# Python regex for multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

Given a string like

```
"points: [prob0 0] [prob1 10] [prob2 5]"
```

How can I write a regex that returns a hash for each problem number and points: `{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 5}`?

I tried using

```
 findall(r"prob\d+ \d+")
```

but still need to process the returned list of strings afterwards. So I wonder if there is a simpler way to express what I'd like to do.

Comment: More on [captuirng groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [`re` usage](https://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should group ("highlight") the pieces of interest. Second, convert the result - a list of tuples - into a dictionry:

```
dict(findall(r"prob(\d+)\s+(\d+)", your_string))
#{'0': '0', '1': '10', '2': '5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use : `out = re.findall(r'prob(\d+)\s(\d+)', s)`

to return: `[('0', '0'), ('1', '10'), ('2', '5')]`

then: `dict(out)`

to return: `{'0': '0', '1': '10', '2': '5'}`

or: `{int(key):int(val) for key,val in dict(out).items()}`

to return: `{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 5}`

or float or whatever format you want the points to be in